# I need to pass a variable in AsyncTask execute but can't figure out how to do it

Tags: java, variables, types, android-asynctask

I have an AsyncTask and from what I can tell I am passing the eventId wrong because in log it shows up as "Ljava.lang.String;@423e4370"

The AsyncTask is:

```
    private class CallCategoryList extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        protected String doInBackground(String... eventId) {
            return readCategoryJSONFeed("http://webservice/service/category_list.php",  eventId.toString());
        }
...
}
```

I call it by doing:

```
new CallCategoryList().execute(fv);
```

fv is got by calling a function that returns it from a class

```
public String getEventByName(List<Event> eventList, String eventName) {
    for (Event event : eventList) {
        if (event.getEventName().equals(eventName)) {
            return event.getId();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Other questions along this line suggest creating another class to hold the variable. Is there not a simple way to pass this variable with execute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construction "String... eventId" is just a shortcut for "String[] eventId". So you should either use eventId[0] or Arrays.toString(eventId) or something appropriate for your logic.

In your case call with a single String argument:

```
new CallCategoryList().execute(fv);
```

is identical to silent array creation:

```
new CallCategoryList().execute(new String[] { fv });
```

Try to google for "java vararg" or take a look into [official docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html).

Comment: I see. I am going to try it now, but I am confused as to why I would need to .toString() if the fv variable holds a string supposedly?

Comment: So far I am getting  `java.lang.NullPointerException`